# ResourceLoader doesn't load the right language

Tags: c#, localization, windows-phone-8.1, multilingual, win-universal-app

I'm localizing my Windows Universal App with the MAT(Multilingual app toolkit). Because the MAT doesn't support the shared project, I've created a Portable Class Libary and I've added the MAT. It looks like this:

[image]

After translating all resources and re-building the project. I've added this code to MainPage:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader loader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("App1.Core/Resources");
string res = loader.GetString("hello");
```

Now when debugging the app, I only get the german resource (wich is the default language of the app), instead of the english translated resource, althought I changed my Device language to English and I've translated all resources.

Anyone an idea? I use the MAT version 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a pain. I contacted MAT team and they said are working on it, releasing a sample of how to use v4 as soon as possible.

As of now, the better solution I could find is to use v3.1, shared `Resources.resw` file and individual `.xlf` translations, but with a workaround not to translate strings twice. 
It's all described here: http://gkokot.com/?p=62